# PDO Insert Array Into Table

Tags: mysql, pdo

Hi experienced people :)

Can someone help me determine why the following PDO MYSQL statement is only inserting a single row into the table when there are more than 1 value in the array?

$availability array values = "1,2,4" for example.

```
  $stmt =$con -> prepare ("INSERT INTO Availability (Periods_P_ID, Users_user_id) VALUES (:period, $user_id)");
  foreach($availability as $periods){
    $stmt -> bindParam(':period', $periods, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       }
   $stmt -> execute();
```

Comment: Put `$stmt -> execute();` into the loop body

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS. It's considered yelling and it's especially annoying in a title.

Comment: Bind **all** your params, not just some of them. `$user_id` is a SQL injection bug.

Comment: Can I ask, is there another way of doing this in one execution?

Comment: yes, I did have the $user_id bound but whilst I was bug fixing I unbound it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to bind the parameter once, outside the loop. But you need to call `execute()` in the loop to insert each row.

```
$stmt =$con -> prepare ("INSERT INTO Availability (Periods_P_ID, Users_user_id) VALUES (:period, :user_id)");
$stmt->bindParam(':period', $periods, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
foreach($availability as $periods){
    $stmt -> execute();
}
```